# How can I create a specific object type at runtime?

Tags: c#, ninject, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have an interface that is implemented by all of my classes which are responsible for exporting data to different formats.

Sample code:

```
public interface IExport
{
    string Exporter();
}

public class ExcelExport : IExport
{
    public string Exporter()
    {
        return "excel";
    }
}

public class PdfExport : IExport
{
    public string Exporter()
    {
        return "pdf";
    }
}
```

I want to get a specific type in runtime, so I know I have to use abstract factory, but don't I know how tp in this example.

Exports are handled by the manager class:

```
 public interface IExportManager
{
    IExport GetExportProvider(ExportType type);
}

public interface IExportFactory
{
    IExport CreateExport(ExportType type);
}

public class ExportManager : IExportManager
{
    private IExportFactory exportFactory;

    public ExportManager(IExportFactory exportFactory)
    {
        this.exportFactory = exportFactory;
    }

    public IExport GetExportProvider(ExportType type)
    {
        return exportFactory.CreateExport(type);
    }
}

public enum ExportType
{
    PDF,
    XLSX
}
```

How can I get the right object instance depending on the type parameter using the GetExportProvider methods?

This is my Ninject module:

```
public class NinModule : NinjectModule
{

    public override void Load()
    {
        this.Bind<IExportFactory>().ToFactory();
        this.Bind<IExportManager>().To<ExportManager>();
        this.Bind<IExport>().To<ExcelExport>();//.WhenInjectedInto<IExportManager>().WithPropertyValue("type", ExportType.XLSX);
        this.Bind<IExport>().To<PdfExport>();//.WhenInjectedInto<IExportManager>().WithPropertyValue("type", ExportType.PDF);
    }
}
```

And the code used to test it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel k = new StandardKernel(new NinModule());

        IExportManager r = k.Get<IExportManager>();
        var pdf = r.GetExportProvider(ExportType.PDF);
        Console.WriteLine(pdf.Exporter());

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, finally I got the solution.

One possibility is to create a custom provider:

```
public class ExportProvider : Provider<IExport>
    {
        protected override IExport CreateInstance(IContext context)
        {
            ExportType type = (ExportType)context.Parameters.First().GetValue(context, null);

            switch (type)
            {
                case ExportType.PDF: return new PdfExport();
                case ExportType.XLSX: return new ExcelExport();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```

And config: `this.Bind<IExport>().ToProvider<ExportProvider>();`

Second possibility I have found:

```
this.Bind<IExport>().To<ExcelExport>().When((q) =>
        {
            ExportType type = (ExportType)q.Parameters.First().GetValue(new DummyContext(), null);
            return type == ExportType.XLSX;
        });

        this.Bind<IExport>().To<PdfExport>().When((q) =>
        {
            ExportType type = (ExportType)q.Parameters.First().GetValue(new DummyContext(), null);
            return type == ExportType.PDF;
        });
```

The GetValue of IParameter requires not null IContext provided. In the When clause we can't get any, but we can use diffrent one, because this parameter is not checked in the method as it look like. So we can create a simple class that implements the IContext interface:

```
public class DummyContext : IContext
    {
        public Ninject.Planning.Bindings.IBinding Binding
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public Type[] GenericArguments
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public IProvider GetProvider()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object GetScope()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool HasInferredGenericArguments
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public IKernel Kernel
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public ICollection<IParameter> Parameters
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public Ninject.Planning.IPlan Plan
        {
            get
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
            set
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public IRequest Request
        {
            get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
        }

        public object Resolve()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about Ninject, but strictly from a C# perspective, why wouldn't this work...

```
public class ExportFactory : IExportFactory
{
    public IExport CreateExport(ExportType type)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case ExportType.PDF:
                return new PdfExport();
            case ExportType.XLSX
                return new ExcelExport();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create dynamic binding in ExportFactory class.
Something like this:

```
if (exportType == ExportType.PDF)
{
  Bind<IExport>().To<PdfExport>().InRequestScope();
}
else if (exportType == ExportType.XLSX)
{
  Bind<IExport>().To<ExcelExport>().InRequestScope();
}
```